# wget replaces '#' with 'index.html#'

Tags: html, wget

When I use wget it has troubles with '#' sign in hrefs. It replaces '#' with 'index.html#' and it usually breaks scripts.

Command I am using is:

```
wget -r -k -l 10 -p -P C:\landings http://example.com/
```

Can something be done about this problem?

Comment: Is it possible that the site actually has the typical `<a href="#">` links intended to be processed by JavaScript? If that's the case, wget is just right.

Comment: For example, website was using href="#contact_form_pop_1" on a button to popup a form. Wget changes this this to href="index.html#contact_form_pop_1" and popup stops working. If I change it back without index popup starts to work on a local copy.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the `-k` switch (aka `--convert-links`) is [meant to do](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-link-conversion):

> After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to
>   make them suitable for local viewing. This affects not only the
>   visible hyperlinks, but any part of the document that links to
>   external content, such as embedded images, links to style sheets,
>   hyperlinks to non-HTML content, etc.

If you don't need it, just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `<a>` tag redirects to `#` ( basically, the default tag is `<a href="#">Text</a>` ).

You'll have to check that the `href` has been properly set, otherwise you'll always get the `index.html#` as a result, instead of the page you are looking for.